# cold folding is not working in netbean for javascript

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, netbeans, ubuntu-12.04, code-folding

I recently shifted to Ubuntu and downloaded Netbean IDE 8.0. I have a large html file that contains javascript, CSS and HTML. I go to **tool->options->editor->folding** and enable code folding for all languages. I restarted netbean even my system but code folding is not working. how to make is work? Thanks

Comment: This question is off-topic.

Comment: well not off-topic. if we not post questions related to netbean in netbean tag then where else ?

Comment: Without having the sample file where it happens, hard to tell. There could be few reasons: if it is really a large page, it could be still being parsed by NetBeans and code folding is not visible until the parsing is finished. Other reason could be syntax error in JS/HTML/CSS code.

Comment: thanks @ladar, it was due to syntax error that netbean pointed out. but the same code was working fine in Visual Studio on windows. I commented out some code and it worked.